# Stuck on trying to get the User to type minutes so Python can convert it to seconds for command line

Tags: python

```
minute = 60
shutdown = ("Shutdown")
log_off = ("Log Off")
restart = ("Restart")
import time
time.sleep(1)
option = input("What would you like to do today?\n Shutdown \n Restart \n Log Off\n")
if option == shutdown:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("You have selected to", shutdown)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    time_shutdown = input("How long do you want until the machine shuts down?(in minutes)")
    number = int(time_shutdown)
    #So at this point I want the minutes converted to seconds
    minutes = number * minute
    #So this should then convert the minutes into seconds
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", minutes])
    print("Your command has been processed...")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    number = int(time_shutdown)
    minutes = number / minute
    print("Your machine will close down in", minutes,"minutes.")


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\test.py", line 23, in <module>
subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", minutes])
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1085, in _execute_child
args = list2cmdline(args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 663, in list2cmdline
needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

And I am desperate for some advice on how to make it work as I have been trying to figure out all day. And I hope that I haven't missed something stupid that I should of put in there.

Could anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Your error seems to be caused by `subprocess.call` trying to interpret your `minutes` argument as a string. Try changing

```
subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", minutes])
```

to

```
subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "-f", "-s", "-t", str(minutes)])
```